# return value 3221225477 after the program finishes

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, return-value

i'm learnig how to code in C.
i have to create a record for a person, with an birthday and a ID number
the code is composed of 3 files

the fist is a header

```
    // definição do tipo
typedef int vetor[10];

typedef struct 
{
    char nome[50];
    vetor nasceu;
    vetor cpf;
} dados ;

void cadastro (dados*, char[50], vetor, vetor);
```

then there is the definitions of the header

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cadastro.h"

void cadastro (dados *usuario, char name[50], vetor ddn, vetor cpf)
{
    int i;
    strcpy(usuario->nome,name);
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        usuario->nasceu[i] = ddn[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        usuario->cpf[i] = cpf[i];
    }
}
```

and the last file uses the header to generate the record

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cadastro.h"

int preenche_cadastro (char a[],vetor b,vetor c)
{
    int i;
    printf ("inserir nome: ");
    gets (a);
    printf("inserir data de nascimento (campos separados por espaco): ");
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&b[i]);
        } 
    printf ("inserir CPF (campos separados por espaco): ");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&c[i]);
    }
    return (0);
}

int imprime_cadastro (dados usuario)
{
    printf("\nnome: %s",usuario.nome);
    printf("\ndata de nascimento: %d / %d / %d\n", usuario.nasceu[0],usuario.nasceu[1],usuario.nasceu[2]);
    printf("CPF:  %d . %d . %d - %d\n", usuario.cpf[0],usuario.cpf[1],usuario.cpf[2],usuario.cpf[3]);
    return(0);
}

int main(void) 
{
    dados new_entry;
    char name[50];
    vetor born, cpf;
    int i;
    preenche_cadastro (name,born,cpf);
    cadastro(&new_entry, name, born, cpf);
    imprime_cadastro(new_entry);
    return (0);
}
```

i don't really know how to debug, but as far as i could tell, the  `Segmentation fault' occurs only at the line

```
return (0);
```

i'm going mad here, can anybody help me?

> sorry for my english, it's not mother language

Comment: Note: `return` is a statement, not a function. The parenthesis are not required and deprecated by most programmers, because they make the code less readable.

Comment: Not everyone deprecates parentheses around the expression after a `return` statement.  And they don't materially affect the readability of the code.  OTOH, the spacing should be consistent — consistency is very important.

Comment: See [Why the `gets()` function is to dangerous to be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) for why you should never write any code that uses `gets()`.

Comment: Important to fix the `gets` problem, as any source of buffer overflow may lead to bizarre errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by accessing out-of-range of array in the line

```
usuario->nasceu[i] = ddn[i];
```

in function `cadastro`, and then the program *happened* to crash there.

Do not invoke *undefined behavior*. Instead of using magic number `10`, you should define the number of elements in the array and use it.

Also note that using values of uninitialized variables having automatic storage duration, which are indeterminate, also invokes *undefined behavior*.

corrected header:

```
// definição do tipo
#define VETOR_NUM 10
typedef int vetor[VETOR_NUM];

typedef struct 
{
    char nome[50];
    vetor nasceu;
    vetor cpf;
} dados ;

void cadastro (dados*, char[50], vetor, vetor);
```

corrected implementation of `cadastro`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cadastro.h"

void cadastro (dados *usuario, char name[50], vetor ddn, vetor cpf)
{
    int i;
    strcpy(usuario->nome,name);
    for (i = 0; i < VETOR_NUM; i++)
    {
        usuario->nasceu[i] = ddn[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < VETOR_NUM; i++)
    {
        usuario->cpf[i] = cpf[i];
    }
}
```

corrected `main()` function:

```
int main(void) 
{
    dados new_entry;
    char name[50];
    vetor born = {0}, cpf = {0}; /* initialize arrays */
    /* i is removed because it wasn't used */
    preenche_cadastro (name,born,cpf);
    cadastro(&new_entry, name, born, cpf);
    imprime_cadastro(new_entry);
    return (0);
}
```

One more note: You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun.

Answer (score 3):

Your first loop should only copy 10 items rather than 50.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        usuario->nasceu[i] = ddn[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This loop in your `cadastro` function:

```
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    usuario->nasceu[i] = ddn[i];
}
```

Seems to not be in line with the size of the `nasceu` arrary:

```
typedef int vetor[10];

typedef struct 
{
    char nome[50];
    vetor nasceu;
    vetor cpf;
} dados ;
```

Have you tried changing to:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    usuario->nasceu[i] = ddn[i];
}
```

?